# Renaming all files in one folder on Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line, osx-yosemite

I have a folder containing dozens of files with no extension. I want to add .txt extension to each of the file. I don't want to rename every file by double clicking and renaming manually. Is there any shell command to perform it in bulk?

Comment: There's always a shell script option: `for file in *; do mv "$file" "$file.txt"; done`.  Mac OS X doesn't come with a `rename` command, so that's as good as it gets, and not really very hard.  You'd run that in a terminal; `cd /Users/yourname/the/sub/directory` and then run the script.  I assume you have `bash` (or `ksh`) as your login shell.  The notation shown is not valid in C shell (`tcsh`).

Comment: Do not destroy questions that have answers.  Consider improving the question instead.

Answer (score 6):

OS X 10.10 and above has multi-file rename built into the Finder.

Using Finder:

- Select the files
- Ctrl-click on one of the selected files
- Choose "Rename N items..." from the menu
- In the sheet that opens, click on "Replace Text" and choose "Add Text" from the menu
- Enter the extension you want (e.g. `.jpg`)
- Press the "Rename" button

Comment: Interesting — I had not noticed that before.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

using find command

```
find <path to folder> -type f  -exec mv {} {}.txt \;
```

`<path to folder>` # path to folder containing your files

`-type f`  # find all files

`-exec mv {} {}.txt` # rename all files and add a .txt extension

Answer (score 1):

I use the [rename](http://plasmasturm.org/code/rename/) utility. You can easily install it with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh):

```
brew install rename
```

then the syntax for achieving what you want would be:

```
rename 's/$/.txt/' *
```

if you want to check what would happen first, run

```
rename -n 's/$/.txt/' *
```